# iOS - Retrieve Picture from Parse currentUser

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, parse-platform, pfquery

I'm using Parse.com as a backend for my iOS app.

I have a class called "User".
In this class I have a flied called "picture" with the users profile picture.

At the moment im kinda stuck on how i can fetch this picture for my currentUser and show it within an UIView (not UIImage) within my storyboard viewcontroller.

Maybe you guys have some sample code for that?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amit, sorry your Code didnt work for me, my app crashed.

Here is my solution:

```
PFUser *cUser = [PFUser currentUser];

PFFile *pictureFile = [cUser objectForKey:@"picture"];

        [pictureFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            if (!error){
                [_currentUserImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"no data!");
                [_currentUserImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile"]]; //Set Custom Image if there is no user picture.

            }
        }];

    }
```